# "Where" statement : contains a certain substring

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL.

I have a **car** table in my database, and there is a `name` column in that table.

Suppose the `name` column of the table contain values:

```
 +----------+
 |   name   |
 +----------+
 | AAA BB   |
  ----------
 | CC D BB  |
  ----------
 | OO kk BB |
  ----------
 | PP B CC  |
  ----------
```

I would like to search the table where `name` column value contains "**BB**" , What is the SQL command to achieve this ?

I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE name LIKE "BB";
```

But it does not work.

**P.S.**

The values in `name` column are random strings.

Please do not ask me to use **IN (...)** , because the values in that column is unpredictable.

**---------Please close this question--------------**

**Sorry, I think I asked the question wrongly. Actually I am asking for a word match not a substring.**

Comment: -1 for not looking up how to use `LIKE` in SQL.

Comment: thank You Tomalak for the link (but not the attitude) +1

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - *No research effort* is the reason. Hover over the downvote button and you'll see that it's the first item listed in the popup. Googling and reading basic documentation is *expected*. The comments stating *why* we downvoted are purely optional.

Comment: Sorry, I think I asked the question wrong. Actually I am asking for a word match not a substring.

Answer (score 45):

You need to include the `%` operator to select records that contain "BB" in the name field, not only the exact value.

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE name LIKE '%BB%';
```

Comment: It might be worth noting now inefficient this is (requires full table scan) and any design that requires this is ... a bad design.

Comment: Without providing alternatives that's just not very helpful Matteo.

Comment: yes, could be inefficient. it depends on how many rows we have on the table. This is the simplest solution

Comment: Sorry, I think I asked the question wrong. Actually I am asking for a word match not a substring.